# Android: In App Billing returns only 1 purchase

Tags: android, in-app-billing, android-developer-api

I have added all of the products as managed products.When I'm querying `getPurchases` it returns only 1 items but when I'm querying `getHistory` than it returns 3 items I'm confused why it is happening?

get purchases Code :

```
Bundle ownedItems = mService.getPurchases(6, getPackageName(), "inapp", null);
```

get Purchase History Code :

```
 Bundle purchaseHistoryBundle = mService.getPurchaseHistory(6, getPackageName(), "inapp", null, new Bundle());
```

I have purchased many products how can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

`getPurchases` needs an Integer that is representing the InApp Billing API. So your call

```
Bundle ownedItems = mService.getPurchases(6, getPackageName(), "inapp", null);
```

must be handling the api version. If you developing InApp Billing version 3, it must be:

```
Bundle ownedItems = mService.getPurchases(3, getPackageName(), "inapp", null);
```

Like described in API:

**Pass the In-app Billing API version (“3”), the package name of your calling app, and the purchase type (“inapp” or "subs") into the method. Here is an example:**

`Bundle ownedItems = mService.getPurchases(3, getPackageName(), "inapp", null)`;

I wonder why it works, anyway I don´t think that this is causing the problem.

The next thing is, the `getPurchases()` returns only not consumed items. If your items are consumed, it will not return these. That´s why history returns it. Like described in API:

```
getPurchases()
```

**This method returns the current un-consumed products owned by the user, including both purchased items and items acquired by redeeming a promo code.**

```
getPurchaseHistory()
```

**This method returns the most recent purchase made by the user for each SKU, even if that purchase is expired, canceled, or consumed.**

My experience with inApp Billing is that this is a huge pain as it is not possible to test every cirumstances through a test account. It seems like a not finished part of android. But we have no other choice to follow exact the api, so I recommend to do it exactly like described.

API and Source Codes:

https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html

https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_reference.html

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-billing/blob/master/TrivialDrive/app/src/main/aidl/com/android/vending/billing/IInAppBillingService.aidl